# How to get back to the default look of Firefox (Iceweasel) UI on CrunchBang?

Tags: firefox, debian, user-interface, crunchbang, iceweasel

I've just installed CrunchBang and I'm exploring the default Firefox front end called Iceweasel.

However, the UI of it seems to be tweaked to be Windows-friendly. Instead of the familiar "File Edit etc" menu bar at the top, there's only a single "Iceweasel" button, like with Firefox on Windows.

I'm pretty sure that there are written rules on how UI layout should be set up on GNU+Linux systems and I'm also pretty sure this is breaking them.

When I used vanilla Debian the Iceweasel UI layout was set properly, so there has to be an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On FireFox, you do Preferences -> Menu Bar (make sure it is checked).  I don't know about IceWeasel, it would probably be the same. To change it back, go View -> Toolbars -> Menu Bar.  Hope it works!!